# mysql calculation based on previous date

Tags: mysql, sql, calculated-columns

I have a curious problem with a calculation that is based on the subtraction of previous day's value from this day's value
Here is the query. Sample data and query result [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b50a4/2)

```
SELECT pd.id,pd.price_date,pd.name_id,pd.class_id,pd.currency_id,pd.price,
         pd.price - (SELECT price
                    FROM price_data as x
                    WHERE x.price_date < pd.price_date
                    AND x.name_id      = pd.name_id
                    AND x.class_id     = pd.class_id
                    AND x.currency_id  = pd.currency_id
      HAVING MAX(x.price_date)) as `change`
      FROM price_data as pd
      WHERE pd.name_id ='BILL'

      ORDER bY pd.name_id,pd.class_id,pd.currency_id,pd.price_date
```

If you look at the result set you will see that the calculation works until it first fails at `row 6`.  It seems to start to add the previous change to the current change.

Is there something wrong with the date determination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query that you want is:

```
SELECT pd.id,pd.price_date,pd.name_id,pd.class_id,pd.currency_id,pd.price,
         pd.price - (SELECT price
                     FROM price_data as x
                     WHERE x.price_date < pd.price_date
                     AND x.name_id      = pd.name_id
                     AND x.class_id     = pd.class_id
                     AND x.currency_id  = pd.currency_id
                     order by x.price_date desc
                     limit 1
                    ) as `change`
FROM price_data as pd
WHERE pd.name_id ='BILL'
ORDER bY pd.name_id,pd.class_id,pd.currency_id,pd.price_date;
```

What is wrong with your original query?  Well, the `having` clause is a non-operation, because it is just checking that the max of the price_date is not 0.  To get what you want, you need to order the data and take the one value you are interested in.